# wso2 identity server - Custom UserStoreManager calling a webservice

Tags: wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

I am actually trying to develop a SAML SSO+ Wso2 identity server authentication implementation. Everything is fine till the time I realized that there are only specific UserStoreManager's like LDAP/JDBC. I have a requirement to use an external web-service as a UserStore and perform the authentication based on the webservice.

I actually realized that I need to create a new UserStoreManager Implementation() . Can you please suggest if you have any references?

Thanks,
Anil Talla

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the already implemented user store managers and write your own custom user store manager. Look at the [AbstractUserStoreManager](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.0.0/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/4.0.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/common/AbstractUserStoreManager.java) class which is extended by both JDBC and LDAP based user managers. Extend this class and override the the methods as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Following blog might be of help to you, [1].
Since you are trying to consume an external web-service as a user store, it will be helpful to have a look at remote user store manager as well, which is shipped with the product and shown in user store management menu of mgt console of IS.

[1] - http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-write-custom-user-store-manager.html